# Linq to trim each word in IList<string[]>

Tags: c#, string, linq, csv, ienumerable

I know this question title is not precise, and there must be a better one, but my English is not so good. And also this question may be duplicate.
Now the task is read csv file, format like following:

```
col1, col2
int1, string1
int2, string2
```

Now I want to use Linq to parse to `IList<string[]>`, so it is easy for later use(each line convert to one object and there are many such csv files for various types). Code as following:

```
IList<string[]> v = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv").Select(
l => l.Split(new char[] { ',', '，' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
//if add this, cannot compile
//.Select(w => w.Trim())
)
.Skip(1).ToList();
```

Please help on the commented line. I want to trim each word, so that they can be converted to integers later. But this will not compile(I know the reason may be that Linq treats w as `IEnumable<Char>`, but how can I **achieve my goal in only one Linq statement**?

Comment: By the way, do you care about lines at all, or you just want an array with words after all?

Comment: one line is one object, and words of lines should not mix up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial attempt you have an error in

```
l.Split(new char[] { ',', '，' } ...
```

since `', '` can't be a *single character*. You want something like this

```
IList<string[]> v = File
  .ReadLines("test.csv")
  .Skip(1) // skip titles
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Select(items => items
    .Select(item => item.Trim()) // trim each item 
    .ToArray())
  .ToList();
```

**Edit**: a shorter version suggested by Evk (see his comment below)

```
IList<string[]> v = File
  .ReadLines("test.csv")
  .Skip(1) // skip titles
  .Select(line => line
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(item => item.Trim()) // trim each item 
    .ToArray())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: You can Trim them right after Split (Split().Select().ToArray()), will save one Select statement.

Comment: @Evk: You're right; I see. But since the question is about `Trim` and there's an *error* in the initial `Split` I've opted to have *two* `Select` in order not to have the Linq being *too complex*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thx, I'm trying your solution. but wondering how you say 'not to be too complex', you mean there's a **complex way**(just curious)?

Comment: @Lei Yang: Evk suggested combining both `Select` into one (see my edit). initailly I refrained from this since I decided to show the Linq step by step.

Comment: Your solution works! And I leaned something new today, thank you!